# Generalization of the well-known combinatorial identity $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n \choose j} j^k = 0$

Tags: combinatorics

The well known identity  $\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {n \choose j} j^k =0$  when $k\lt n$ can be viewed as a particular case, applied to a uniform distribution, of a more general relation, defined for a general distribution $\{p_i\}, 1\le i\le n, \sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$, for $k \lt n$: 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \sum_{|J|=j} P_J^k = 0$$ 
where $\sum_{|J|=j}$ is the sum over all the subsets of size j of $\{1..n\}$ , and $P_J=\sum_{j\in J}p_j$.
This more general relation can be proven by proving an intermediate result, then the general relation  follows. 
The intermediate result is that, for any distribution, $\sum_{|J|=j} P_J^k$ can be expressed as a weighted sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{u=1}^k {n-k \choose j-u} \alpha_{k,u}$, where $\alpha_{k,u}$ are independent of j and $\alpha_{k,k}=1$. For example, one can show quite easily that: $\sum_{|J|=j} P_J = {n-1 \choose j-1}$ , i.e., the same as a uniform distribution, and that: $\sum_{|J|=j} P_J^2 = {n-2 \choose j-2} + {n-2 \choose j-1} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2 $.
However the rest of the proof based on induction on the exponent is quite tedious, several pages long. Is there another proof of this relation ?

If an analytic form exists in the general case, when applied to a uniform probability, the result should be such that:  $\alpha_{k,u}n^k=\sum_{i=1}^nS(k,i)i!{n \choose i}{k-i \choose u-i}$ where S is the Stirling number of 2nd order.
This can be proven with the well-known relation of Stirling numbers $j^k=\sum_{i=0}^jS(k,i)i!{j \choose i}$ and Chu-Vandermonde identity.

Proof by induction can be found in: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314243075_On_Von_Schelling_Formula_for_the_Generalized_Coupon_Collector_Problem

Comment: Hint: Let $\left[q\right]$ be the set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,q\right\}$ for each $q \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $P_J^k = \sum\limits_{f : \left[k\right] \to \left[n\right]; \  f\left(\left[k\right]\right) \subseteq J} \prod\limits_{i\in\left[k\right]} p_{f\left(i\right)}$. Now you need to check that for each $f : \left[k\right] \to \left[n\right]$, the terms containing the corresponding $\prod\limits_{i\in\left[k\right]} p_{f\left(i\right)}$ cancel. To prove this, observe that $f\left(\left[k\right]\right)$ is a proper subset of $\left[n\right]$, since its size is $\leq k < n$.

Comment: can you detail your hint for k=1 or k=2 for example ? Thanks

Comment: I've turned my hint into a proof that's now on my website. See my answer for details.

Comment: Trivial remark: Your sum $\sum_{u=1}^k$ should start at $u=0$, to adapt to the case when $k=0$.

Comment: This is correct. However it implies handling additional weigths: alpha(k,0)=0 for k>0. Also in my application case, k is necessarily positive.

Answer (score 1):

The  following  calculation  is  likely  to  be  based  on  the  wrong
interpretation of the question since the  OP informs us that this is a
difficult combinatorial identity.

The sum in question is given by

$$k! [z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n (1-\exp(p_q z)).$$

Now observe that  $1-\exp(p_q z)$ starts at $z$ namely  with $-p_q z -
p_q^2 z^2/2-\cdots$  so the  product starts at  $[z^n]$ and  hence the
coefficients on $[z^k]$ where $k\lt n$ are zero, which is the claim.

Comment: Agreed this is a much more straigthforward way to prove the generalization of the identity. I was more interested in an alternative version of proof of what I call intermediate result. I would really appreciate a reference to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what the OP is seeking is the following formula, which
follows by inspection, namely that when $j\ge k$ we have

$$\sum_{|J|=j} P_J^k =
\sum_{q=1}^k \sum_{|J|=j} \sum_{Q\subseteq J, \; |Q|=q}
k! [z^k] \prod_{r\in Q} (\exp(rz)-1)
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k \sum_{|J|=j} \sum_{Q\subseteq J, \; |Q|=q}
\prod_{r\in Q} (\exp(rz)-1)
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k \sum_{|J|=j} [u^q]
\prod_{r\in J} (1+ u(\exp(rz)-1))
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q]
\prod_{r\in P} (1+ v(1+ u(\exp(rz)-1)))
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q]
\prod_{r\in P} (1+ v + uv(\exp(rz)-1))
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q]
\prod_{r\in P} (1+ v -uv + uv\exp(rz)).$$

This is

$$k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q] (1+v-uv)^n
\prod_{r\in P} \left(1 + \frac{uv}{1+v-uv} \exp(rz)\right)
\\ = k! [z^k]  \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q] (1+v-uv)^n
\sum_{Q\subseteq P} \left( \frac{uv}{1+v-uv}\right)^{|Q|}
\prod_{q\in Q} \exp(qz)
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q] (1+v-uv)^n
\sum_{Q\subseteq P} \left( \frac{uv}{1+v-uv}\right)^{|Q|}
\left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k.$$

This becomes

$$\sum_{q=1}^k [v^j] [u^q] 
\sum_{Q\subseteq P} (uv)^{|Q|} (1+v-uv)^{n-|Q|}
\left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k
\\ = \sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; |Q|\le j} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k
 [v^{j-|Q|}]  \sum_{q=|Q|}^k  [u^{q-|Q|}] (1+v-uv)^{n-|Q|}
\\ = \sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; |Q|\le j} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k
 [v^{j-|Q|}]  \sum_{q=|Q|}^k  {n-|Q|\choose q-|Q|} 
(-1)^{q-|Q|} v^{q-|Q|} (1+v)^{n-q}
\\ = \sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; |Q|\le j} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k
\sum_{q=|Q|}^k  {n-|Q|\choose q-|Q|} 
(-1)^{q-|Q|} [v^{j-q}] (1+v)^{n-q}
\\ = \sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; |Q|\le j} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k
\sum_{q=|Q|}^k  {n-|Q|\choose q-|Q|} 
(-1)^{q-|Q|} {n-q\choose j-q}.$$

Note that the  subsets with $j\ge |Q|\gt k$ do  not contribute because
the range of the  second inner sum is up to $k.$  We re-write one more
time to isolate the dependency on $j$ and get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{q=1}^k {n-q\choose j-q}
\sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; 1\le |Q|\le q}
{n-|Q|\choose q-|Q|}  (-1)^{q-|Q|} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k.}$$

Here  we have  started  $q$ at  one  because the  empty  set does  not
contribute, with  the power sum being  zero. It thus appears  that the
queried constants are given by

$$\alpha_{k,q} = \sum_{Q\subseteq P, \; 1\le |Q|\le q}
{n-|Q|\choose q-|Q|}  (-1)^{q-|Q|} \left(\sum_{l\in Q} l\right)^k.$$

Comment: Hi, interesting, very interesting.

Comment: Hi, interesting, very i.. You end up with binomial coeeficients in n-q whereas my constants are in n-k, but important thing is the indendence from j. I have not yet checked that your derivation correctly implies the second condition (constant is 1 when u=k). If I understand well, your j >=k limitation comes from line 13 (numbering your proof) , where exponent of v must be positive or null, am I correct ? My humble suggestion is notation P line 4 be explicit as the reference set, i.e. |P|=n, you need to go to 7 to be sure of it. I'm still struggling to be sure of the 8->9, (reference ?).BR

Comment: 8->9, I got it.OK

Comment: My sunday homework: it's fairly easy to derive (my) alpha coefficients from your expression and indeed, they give the right result for k=1 and k=2 and for the uniform case (with stirling numbers). This seems to indicate that your expression is correct even for j<k. However proving that alpha(k,k)=1 seems to require additional material.

Comment: just figured out that from your decompostion, it is possible to derive an expression giving the sum of the k-power of all j-subsets probabilities as a sum of k-power of all 1..k-subsets probabilities (for j>=k). If n=100, j=50 and k=5, this is 1.27*10^21 less operations to perform. Nice!

Comment: I meant: this is 1.27*10^21 times less operations

Comment: I kindly ask that you do not contact me personally per email as I cannot and will not answer these. Please post to MSE if you have additional questions. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Hello,I’m completing a paper/report related to a question  I submitted on MSE and that you answered.I would appreciate if you have comments  on the part I copy below (rest of paper is not yet completed) and if you agree/disagree with the wordings. Many Thanks and best regards.

Comment: During the finalization phase of this document, a major contribution was made by Marko Riedel ) who gave an analytic form of decomposition when j≥k (in fact j>k, the analytic form lending to a tautology for j=k).

Answer (score 0):

This is Exercise 6.50 **(b)** in my [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf), version of 10 January 2019. (The numbering of the exercises might change, but you can find [the version of 10 January 2019 archived on github](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10).)

Note that the proof I give there is really written up "from scratch" (and I spend a while ruminating on trivialities about sums of products because my ring is noncommutative; not sure if you need that generality). You probably will find Lemma 7.222 trivial, and maybe Lemma 7.223 known. Parts **(c)** and **(d)** of that exercise give a formula for the sum in the case when $k=n$ (rather than $k<n$). Part **(a)** gives a formula in the general case, but your mileage may vary about how useful it is.

Comment: i agree 18(b) is a proof  of the generalisation of the combinatorial identity, however as I said, I'm interested in what I called the intermediate result (decomposition of sum of powers of j-subset probabilites on a basis of binomial coefficients) and computation of the

Comment: .. computation of the coefficients. Regards,

Comment: Ah! That's indeed a more interesting question. My computations show that $\alpha_{k,u} = \sum\limits_{a \in \operatorname{Par}^{\leq n}} \dbinom{k}{a} \dbinom{k - \ell\left(a\right)}{u - \ell\left(a\right)} m_a$, where I use the following notations: $\mathbb{N} = \left\{0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$. The notation $\dbinom{k}{a}$ is a multinomial coefficient, defined to be $0$ if the sum of the entries of $a$ is not $k$. The number $\ell\left(a\right)$ is the length of a partition $a$. The set $\operatorname{Par}^{\leq n}$ is the set of all partitions of length $\leq n$. The ...

Comment: ... polynomial $m_a$ is the $a$-th monomial symmetric polynomial in the $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$; in other words, it is the sum of all monomials whose exponents are a reordering of the entries of $a$. But I'm not sure how useful this is. One consequence (using some symmetric function theory) is that the $\alpha_{k,u}$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-polynomials in the power sums $p_1^q + p_2^q + \cdots + p_n^q$. But I suspect there is a simpler way to prove this.